# A group with only one element from Order 2

Tags: group-theory

need to prove that for a group with only one element from  Order 2, this element belong to the center of the group,
how to prove that?

Comment: What on earth does "organ" mean here?

Comment: I think you meant 'element' instead of 'organ'. But still !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $G$ be a group with a unique $\sigma$ of order $2$, and let $g \in G$ be arbitrary. What is the order of $g\sigma g^{-1}$?